# ValueError: invalid vector on line 440902 | while loading wiki.ar.vec using gensim.models.keyedvectors.word2vec() function

Tags: python, arabic, gensim, word2vec, word-embedding

I'm trying to load wiki.ar.vec arabic word embedding file using word2vec function from gensim.

Below is the code use to load embedding file.

```
import gensim.models.keyedvectors as word2vec 
print( "Word Embedding is loading")
embedding = word2vec.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('/home/user/Documents/wiki.ar.vec', binary=False)
print( "Word Embedding is loaded")
```

Facing the Error describe in below screenshot:

[image]

or any other way to load wiki.ar.vec embedding file?

Any suggestion and answers are highly appriciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error indicates the file is not in the proper format, at that specified line/vector.

Where did the file come from? Are you sure it's a binary-format file of the right format?

Have you tried re-downloading the file to ensure it hasn't been corrupted or truncated?